# Is there a way to have a multiline shebang for a Groovy script?

Tags: bash, groovy

The following almost works:

```
#!/bin/bash
/* 2>&1 >/dev/null
script_dir=$(dirname "$0")

export GROOVY_HOME=${script_dir}/../../../../Tools/groovy/groovy-2.0.2

exec ${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovy -cp "${script_dir}:$(ls ${script_dir}/build/lib/runtime/*.jar | xargs echo | sed -e 's| |:|g')" "$0"
*/ // 2>&1 >/dev/null

println("aoeu")
```

The only problem is that the shell globs /* and tries to execute it. In the end, all I really want to do is to be able to build the Groovy script's classpath without having to have two separate scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
script_dir="$(cd $(dirname $0) >/dev/null; pwd -P)"

function after-bangshe() {
  sed -e '1,/^!#$/d' "$1"
}

if [ -z "${GROOVY_HOME}" ]
then
  echo 'GROOVY_HOME must be defined.' >&2
  exit 1
fi

CLASSPATH="${script_dir}" "${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovy" -e "$(after-bangshe $0)" "$@"
exit
!#
println 'aoeu'
```

The output of `cd` is redirected to `/dev/null` in case `CDPATH` is set (which makes `cd` noisy).

`CLASSPATH` is set to the script directory so that any support classes can be found.

The `sed` command strips out everything after the `!#` line.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try the technique below, which is independent of Groovy syntax (and does not normally produce output on `stderr`):

```
#!/bin/sh
script_dir=$(dirname "$0")
export GROOVY_HOME="$script_dir/../../../../Tools/groovy/groovy-2.0.2"

awk 'mark_on{print}/^__END__$/{mark_on=1}' "$0" >/tmp/$$.groovy

"$GROOVY_HOME/bin/groovy" -cp "$script_dir:$(echo "$script_dir"/build/lib/runtime/*.jar | tr " " :)" /tmp/$$.groovy
status=$?

rm -f /tmp/$$.groovy

exit $status

__END__

println("aoeu")
```

Also notice the simplification in the classpath calculation; remember that globbing (wildcard expansion) is performed by the shell, not by the command that takes the arguments, so you do not have to (nor do you want to) use `ls` in this case.

---

The curly brackets `${}` in your original code are technically superfluous in this case (they are purely stylistic); they *would* be needed if you had for example to append a string directly after a variable substitution where there is no clear break between the variable name and what follows, e.g. you cannot say `$my_varsome_string` but you can write `${my_var}some_string`, or any of `$my_var"some_string"` or `$my_var'some_string'` or `"$my_var"some_string` or `"$my_var""some_string"`.  I removed the braces for  "minimalistic" purposes and in order to illustrate the above, but again, it's perfectly fine to keep them for stylistic reasons.

The quotes I added consistently in the code above protect you from potential blanks and certain other special characters inside `$GROOVY_HOME`. Feel free to remove them in order to simplify quoting (and be minimalistic) if you know `$GROOVY_HOME` will not contain blanks.

Comment: Can you explain in some detail (or point to relevant documentation) what that `awk` line is doing? What's the significance of `mark_on` (which seems to be some variable)?

Comment: Never mind, https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56429/how-to-print-all-lines-after-a-match-up-to-the-end-of-the-file/56517#56517 shows a way to do it with `sed` which makes more sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want to write a groovy / shell polyglot.

I don't know groovy, but from the documentation it seems [] is a valid groovy command, creating an empty list.

Then you could write it as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
[ /*  2> /dev/null > /dev/null
script_dir=$(dirname "$0")

export GROOVY_HOME=${script_dir}/../../../../Tools/groovy/groovy-2.0.2

exec ${GROOVY_HOME}/bin/groovy -cp "${script_dir}:$(ls ${script_dir}/build/lib/runtime/*.jar | xargs echo | sed -e 's| |:|g')" "$0"
*/
    ]

println("aoeu")
```

Groovy will read [] and ignore it, and bash will call [ with /*, which will cause an error that is ignored. But it will not run any unexpected programs.